# Why am i getting Unknown column 'list_class.pk_class_id' in 'on clause' error?

Tags: sql, join

I want to get student details from different tables with given academic year and class.
Query that i used is:

```
 SELECT
  list_acad_years.acad_year,
  a.fk_stu_id,
  tbl_stu_details.stu_fname,
  tbl_stu_details.stu_sname,
  a.fk_section_id,
  b.fk_class_id,
  list_class.class_name,
  list_sections.section_code
FROM
  tbl_stu_details,
  list_class,
  list_sections,
  list_acad_years
INNER JOIN
  tbl_stu_class AS a
ON
  (
    list_acad_years.pk_acad_year_id = a.fk_year_id
  )
INNER JOIN
  tbl_stu_class AS b
ON
  (list_class.pk_class_id = b.fk_class_id)
WHERE
  (
    list_acad_years.acad_year = '2019'
  ) AND(list_class.class_name = '10')
```

it shows the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'list_class.pk_class_id' in 'on clause'
```

columns of my table are:

**tbl_stu_class:**

```
pk_stu_cls_id`, `fk_stu_id`, `fk_year_id`, `fk_class_id`, `fk_section_id`, `current_yr`
```

**list_class:**

```
`pk_class_id`, `class_name`, `class_code`, `fk_user_id`
```

**list_sections:**

```
pk_section_id`, `section_code`, `section_description`, `fk_user_id`
```

**list_acad_years:**

```
`pk_acad_year_id`, `acad_year`, `acad_year_code`, `fk_user_id`
```

**tbl_stu_details:**

```
`pk_stu_id`, `stu_id`, `username`, `stu_fname`, `stu_mname`, `stu_sname`
```

**list_sections:**

```
`pk_section_id`, `section_code`, `section_description`, `fk_user_id`
```

Why did it say unknown column when the column is present?
It would be great help if you can help me make this query better...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact query which generated the error?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: yes i have just copied the query from my editor which has generated mentioned error

Comment: @GordonLinoff as I am new to joins could you just provide me a proper link or an example from which I can learn more about it....

Comment: Look at the documentation for any database on the `FROM` clause and joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Inner join will alway connect to the last table in from statement if you are using multiple FROM table. 
I have just change the position of `INNER JOIN`

try this let me know if it works.

```
SELECT
  list_acad_years.acad_year,
  a.fk_stu_id,
  tbl_stu_details.stu_fname,
  tbl_stu_details.stu_sname,
  a.fk_section_id,
  b.fk_class_id,
  list_class.class_name,
  list_sections.section_code
FROM
  tbl_stu_details,
  list_class INNER JOIN
  tbl_stu_class AS b
ON
  (list_class.pk_class_id = b.fk_class_id),
  list_sections,
  list_acad_years
INNER JOIN
  tbl_stu_class AS a
ON
  (
    list_acad_years.pk_acad_year_id = a.fk_year_id
  )
WHERE
  (
    list_acad_years.acad_year = '2019'
  ) AND(list_class.class_name = '10')
```

Comment: You can accept whatever answer you like.  Any code that has commas in the `FROM` clause is just a bad, bad example of SQL.

Comment: yes. @GordonLinoff i agreed to that the excution of this query cost is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using old-style joins.  Period.  To make matters worse, you are combining them with new style joins.

The names of the tables are not understood across commas.  That limits the scope of the definitions.

You appear to know how to write `JOIN`s correctly.  So, just fix the `FROM` clause and your code should work.